# Iterate 2D Python List and Modify values from List- Tuples

Tags: python, json, list, tuples

community.

I'm stuck with a very strange issue in python.
I'm trying to build a Backend and I want to add a function in which
I would be able to change the values that the user send me.

For example:
User json request :
[ {
"banana":2
"orange":5
"apple":12 }]

So far, this request comes to my backend as a list.
With a for loop, I'm trying to change everyone's value from 2 to 0.

For i n list:
i[1]=0

But then : TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Please send help.
Thanks a lot!

CODE EXAMPLE

```
def calculate_ade( ores: schema.usersores,db: Session):
    entoles = db.query(model.eergou).filter(model.eergou.a_ores > 0 ).all()
    ores = list(ores)
    for i in entoles:
        for p in ores:
           if (i.a_ores==0):
               break
           if (p[1] - i.a_ores >= 0):
               i.kata_ores=i.k_ores
               p[1]-=int(i.a_ores)
```

Comment: You probably are getting tuple instead of a list. But to know for sure you need to upload minimal example, or the whole code, if it's small

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated with a part of my code

Comment: A few suggestions/questions: (1) choose a different name for the variable `tuple`, since `tuple` is the name of a built-in type in Python; (2) you show `p[1]` having its value updated, but I don't see the definition of `p` - can you please show the code where `p` is defined? (3) can you please update your question to include the values for `ores` and `entoles`?

Comment: Yes @constantstranger, you are right.  I updated it again. 
So ores, is the json file  [ { "banana":2 "orange":5 "apple":12 }]. When the second if is true, then I want to change the values of banana, orange and apple.